# Moving from Azure AD Graph to Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a SAAS product for Office 365.  It was developed about three years ago and uses Microsoft Azure AD Graph for authentication and to carry out various tasks using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.

I would like to start planning the migration from AAD Graph to MS Graph and have read in this post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/

“*For developers with existing apps that call Azure AD Graph, we will provide guidance for those who want to switch their apps over to Microsoft Graph (from Azure AD Graph).  **Additionally, we’ll do it in such a way that existing users for your applications won’t need to re-consent to your application to access directory data through Microsoft Graph**.*”

I have scoured the internet but have been unable to locate any advice or guidance regarding the migration process.

I would appreciate it if you could point me in the direction of the guidance or if none is available yet give me a rough idea as to when it will be available.

Comment: That web page says they would like to hear from you. Did you try posting a comment there? We certainly would have no idea of when such guidance would be made available if not already.

Comment: Yes I did post a comment there ( in January ) - it is still "Awaiting Moderation".    I also found a group email address at the end of tutorial video on the graph end-point and mailed that - but it just bounced back.